# How to set the size of a hash-table of a hash-index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, hashtable

I'm using MongoDB to store data for experiments. 
Each document represent a web page with unique ID and URL. There are approximately 500M documents.
I need to map some data based on a URL string field, so I built a hash-typed index for that field.

I have some performance issue when querying based on URL, so I wanted to check what's the index's hash-table size and whether I can make it bigger.

I've failed to find any help regarding this question online and on Mongo's documentation.

Thanks